# Unable to complete card flipping animation when selected

Tags: html, css

I have cards with content on both sides.

When a user clicks on the card, `.card-back` is meant to turn over and display `.card-front`. However, both images are constantly displayed.

I suspect this is because of my `style.css` order, but I cannot figure it out.

To note that `.car` is the image on `.card-back` and `.logo` is the image on `.card-front`.

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/camerongdev/pen/NWMoWXV

```
.card{
    position: relative;
    height: 175px;
    width: 125px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: black;
}

.card-area{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

.car{
    position: absolute;
    width: 165px;
    height: 105px;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    margin-top: 35px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.logo{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 35px;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card.flipped .card-back{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card.flipped .card-front{
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

Comment: html is missing. please consider using a runnable snippet

Comment: How are you implementing the click action? Javascript? Your link only has HTML and CSS.

Comment: @Sarah yes click action happens in JS, it adds class 'flipped' to the same class as 'card' .  To view the 'front-card' on codepen, will need to add 'flipped' to that same class manually.